# SharePoint Features Properties

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-studio, feature

I have to set my feature properties from VS.
When I *double-click* on the file **FeatureName.Feature** ,
I do not see the properties window but VS open the feature design manager.
How can I change the properties? I do not want change the manifest.xml directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following step:

1. Double click om the file FeatureName.Feature
2. Then on the feature main window press F4.

This will show the properties pane.

Comment: Thanks! I was just pressing F4 and VS shows the file properties (not the SP properties)

Comment: Put your cursor near your main window. Just like close to where Items in this package written.